# Hiding Menu options based on AD Group Membership

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a metisMenu in my ASP.Net MVC app, what I am looking to do is hide some options based on the users AD Group membership.

The app is currently using windows integrated authentication (Intranet Application).

What is the best way to do this?

I am presuming I could do a viewbag option which then if true or flase either shows or hides, but that would mean I would have to code something for every action?

The menu is part of the shared layout which is below

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>CCL Support System</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="~/img/favicon.png" />
    @*CSS Declerations*@
    <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/Content/plugins/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/Content/ccl.less" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="~/Content/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="~/Content/themify-icons.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    @*JavaScript Declerations*@
    <script src="~/Scripts/less.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/jquery-2.1.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/plugins/metisMenu/metisMenu.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/scripts/sb-admin-2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/MicrosoftAjax.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/expand.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body class="ccl-body">

    <div id="wrapper">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top ccl-header" role="navigation">
            <div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown navbar-profile">
                        <a style="z-index: 1" href="#" class="dropdown-toggle navbar-profile-icon" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="ti-settings menu-icon"></span><span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Edit", "Profile" )">Edit User Details</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="logo-box">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="ccl-logo" href="@Url.Action("index", "Home" )"><img src="~/img/logo.png" width="75" height="73" alt="" /></a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
                <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="@Url.Action("index", "Home" )"><span class=" ti-info menu-icon"></span>Information<span class="ti-angle-right menu-carret pull-right"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("About", "Home")">About</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("License", "Home")">Licenses</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("Bug", "Home")">Bug Report</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="@Url.Action("Search", "Password" )"><span class=" ti-key menu-icon"></span>Reset Passsword</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>

        <!-- Main Panel -->
        <div id="page-wrapper" class="content">
            @if (IsSectionDefined("title"))
            {
                <div id="page-block" class="page-block-header row">
                    <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-10">
                        @RenderSection("title", false)
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
            @if (IsSectionDefined("subtitle"))
            {
                <div id="page-block" class="page-block-two row">
                    <div class="col-lg-offset-1 col-lg-10">
                        @RenderSection("subtitle", false)
                    </div>
                </div>
            }
            @RenderBody()
        </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Footer -->
    <div class="navbar ccl-footer">
        <div class="pull-right">
            <p>&copy; 2014 Computer Concepts Ltd</p>
        </div>
    </div>


</body>
</html>
```

If we look at the menu more closely (snippet below)

```
div class="navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation">
                <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="@Url.Action("index", "Home" )"><span class=" ti-info menu-icon"></span>Information<span class="ti-angle-right menu-carret pull-right"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("About", "Home")">About</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("License", "Home")">Licenses</a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="@Url.Action("Bug", "Home")">Bug Report</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="@Url.Action("Search", "Password" )"><span class=" ti-key menu-icon"></span>Reset Passsword</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
```

I am looking to hide certain options within this

What would be the best way, would I need to create a custom authentication class??  if so does anyone have any good links on how to do this?

So the end result would be if user is in XYZ AD Group then show

```
<li>
                            <a href="@Url.Action("Search", "Password" )"><span class=" ti-key menu-icon"></span>Reset Passsword</a>
                        </li>
```

Otherwise hide it.

Comment: You can create you own `ActionFilter` that adds a `ViewBag` property (and register it globally) or use `@Html.Action()` to call a child action that renders the menu (where that method determines what to display based the users role)

Answer (score 0):

You can use MvcSiteMapProvider's [security trimming](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Security-Trimming) feature to do this in a few steps.

1. Configure the [AuthorizeAttribute](https://www.google.co.th/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=8&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CE0QFjAH&url=http%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Flibrary%2Fsystem.web.mvc.authorizeattribute%2528v%3Dvs.118%2529.aspx&ei=501yVKbcFNXToASqloHoAQ&usg=AFQjCNFf5AUmS1vuIrEtL7A60HjXWkX-Mg&sig2=RQN-7-y4ElD4qg-vS2wQvQ&bvm=bv.80185997,d.cGU) on your action methods (which supports roles/users/AD/forms authentication).
2. Install [MvcSiteMapProvider](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcSiteMapProvider.MVC4/) via NuGet.
3. Create an hierarchy of your site in the [Mvc.sitemap XML file](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-sitemap-nodes-in-XML) and/or using [.NET attributes](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-sitemap-nodes-using-.NET-attributes) and/or using [dynamic node providers](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Defining-sitemap-nodes-using-IDynamicNodeProvider).
4. Add the [@Html.MvcSiteMap().Menu() HTML helper](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/HtmlHelper-extensions) to your layout page (or create your own Menu HTML helper that has similar functionality if it doesn't suit your needs).
5. Customize the templates in the `/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/` folder to conform to your page layout.

   - Documentation Wiki: https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki
   - Blog with Downloadable Demos: http://www.shiningtreasures.com/?tag=/MvcSiteMapProvider
   - MvcSiteMapProvider Questions on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mvcsitemapprovider

**Full Disclosure:** I am a major project contributor of MvcSiteMapProvider.

If you don't want to add a 3rd party library, this will take a bit of work to do. You would have to create your own HTML helpers that respond to the authorize attribute (or something similar). You could cannibalize the [AuthorizeAttributeAclModule](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/blob/master/src/MvcSiteMapProvider/MvcSiteMapProvider/Security/AuthorizeAttributeAclModule.cs) to determine whether to show or hide your HTML helper nodes.

Comment: ok is there any documentation on this?  I am not against using a 3rd party library as long as there is some support and documentation

Comment: I updated my question with (more) links to the docs. The documentation on Security Trimming is [here](https://github.com/maartenba/MvcSiteMapProvider/wiki/Security-Trimming), and there is a beginner's tutorial [here](http://www.shiningtreasures.com/post/2013/08/07/MvcSiteMapProvider-40-a-test-drive).